# How to print the result of a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml

I'm working on getting the result of a function printed onto the screen.

The function works, it calculates the fibonaaci sequence based on an integer.

But I don't know how to get it displayed using innerHTML.

Here's the code:

```js
var number = document.getElementsByClassName('enter')[0].value;

var a = parseInt(number);

function fib(a) {
    if (a <= 1) return 1;
    return fib(a - 1) + fib(a - 2);

    var print = document.getElementsByClassName('sequence').innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="form">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="10" placeholder="enter a number (max of 50)" class="enter">
  <input onclick="fib()" type="submit">
</form>
<p class="sequence"></p>
```

Comment: Do you want to maybe clean up your code a bit? As it is right now, it's not even going to compile, as you can see from the snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your algorithm is that you are using recursion to find the sequence. This is a very expensive operation, as it performs many operations. Using that, it's very easy to exceed the `maximum call size`.

A better option would be to create an array with numbers and populate the array by taking only the last and second to last numbers. With this approach, you can enter a number up to 1,000 and get results almost instantly. Try it out here.

```js
var sequence = document.getElementById("sequence");
var btn = document.getElementById("getSequence");

function fib(a) {
    var numbers = [1,1];
    var num = +(document.getElementById("num").value);
    if (num) {
        while (numbers.length < num) {
            numbers[numbers.length] = numbers[numbers.length - 1] + numbers[numbers.length - 2];
        }
    sequence.innerHTML = numbers.join(',');
    }
    else {
        sequence.innerHTML = "Select a number first ";
    }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var input = +(document.getElementById("num").value);
    fib(input);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num" min="1" max="1000" />

<button id="getSequence">Get Sequence</button>

<p id="sequence"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, you are missing a close bracket in the `fib(Number)` function; that may be a typo. You are also missing the end quotation mark in the last line of the HTML in the class definition.

The error occurs in the `var print...` line. `document.getElementsByClassName(class)` returns an array of all HTML objects with the class `class`. Therefore, the return value does not have the property `innerHTML`, so you should be getting an error there.

There are two simple solutions to that.

1 - Get an element from the array

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sequence')[0].innerHTML = a;
```

2 - Assign an ID to the `<p>` element

```
<p class="sequence" id="out"></p>
=================================================================================
document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last line is rather weird since you want to set innerHTML. Try this one:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sequence').innerHTML = fib(a);
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp

Comment: This is wrong because `className` returns a collection, not a single element

Answer (score 0):

True it would not compile from the snippet.

Largely your problem is here:

```
var print = document.getElementsByClassName('sequence').innerHTML = a;
```

Two things:

1)  You don't need to set a variable to print or to change an html class.  So not sure what "print" means but .innerHTML is a getter or a setter depending on how it's used.  I think you mean to change the value of this variable to get the output to flow into 'sequence.';

2)  "id" is used for a single element, "class" is used for a group of elements.  I'm guessing you're more interested in the former.  So:

```
document.getElementById('sequence').innerHTML = a;
```

...should accomplish what you're after if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

print is a built in function, so you can not set stuff to it ( or at least you should not ), Also getElementsByClassName returns an array that has to be looped through

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('sequence');
var i;
for( i = 0 ; i < p.length ; i++ ){ p[i].innerHTML = 1234; }
```